# South deletes field values when you migrate a field name change for not null fields

Tags: python, django-south

I remember reading somewhere that you should not set TextField or CharField with null=True in models, that you should just have blank=True. I recently had a field called Reciept, and the spelling error bugged me, so I changed the value to Receipt. This was a FileField and as this was just a varchar field in mysql, I had initially set blank=True but not null=True. When I made the spelling change and schema migration for South, South complained that

```
? The field receipt does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
? Since you are removing this field, you MUST specify a default
? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
?  3. Disable the backwards migration by raising an exception.
? Please select a choice:
```

I selected 2, and entered '' as the default one off value, thinking that if South came across any fields with a null value on reverse migration, it would set it to the empty string. Instead it deleted all the field values putting '' in instead for the forward change.

What am I missing here.? I expected south to keep all the old data. How do you get South to carry over data for fields that are defined as being not null? If I had made this change in SQL, the rename would have been a one liner. Should this not be simple in South too?